# How do I turn this sign up/opt-in form into a pop up box?

Tags: popup

I am trying to turn this opt-in form into a pop-up box with a timed delay and lighted background. For example, it would appear directly in the center on the screen after 10 seconds when a visitor visits my site. They would also have the option to close the box, but they would still be able to see the website in the background, dimmed. The code to the opt-in box is below. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="http://oi.vresp.com?fid=524a3264c1" target="vr_optin_popup" onsubmit="window.open( 'http://www.verticalresponse.com', 'vr_optin_popup', 'scrollbars=yes,width=600,height=450' ); return true;" >

  <div style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 11px; width: 160px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #0D2EC0D; background: #540DEC;">
    <strong><span style="color: #D2EC0D;">Enter Email For Updates</span></strong>
    <p style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><span style="color: #f00;">* </span><span style="color: #333333">required</span></p>
    <label style="color: #D2EC0D;">Email Address:</label>    <span style="color: #f00">* </span>
    <br/>
    <input name="email_address" size="15" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 3px;"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" style="margin-top: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 3px;"/><br/>
    <br/><span style="color: #333333"><a title="Email Marketing by VerticalResponse" href="http://www.verticalresponse.com">Email Marketing</a> by VerticalResponse</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no code, only text. Please update your question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

make your div and give id to it then use it as popup using jquery

```
$('#IdofElement').dialog('option', 'modal', true);
```

you need jquery main file to use this

http://jqueryui.com/dialog

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VXrE4/3/ i have made the example for you click on the link and make it as you wish.